# How to Execute Callback in Lua with Parameters

Tags: lua, callback, coronasdk

I'm trying to append additional logic to a callback function.  Problem is the callback also requires a parameter.

I have this function, last param is the callback:

```
game.showAlert( 
  "Title", 
  "Message",
  function( event )
    if (event.action == "clicked") then
      --Do stuff
    end
  end
)
```

I'm trying to inject some additional logic after the callback by doing this:

```
game.showAlert = function (title, message, tblButtons, tblListener) 
  function onComplete()
    --Execute listener that was passed in
    if (tblListener and type(tblListener) == "function") then
        tblListener()
    end

    --Do other stuff
  end

  native.showAlert(title, message, tblButtons, onComplete)
end
```

When i call `tblListener()` I get an error saying that `event` is `nil`, which does make sense.

Question is, how can I execute the callback as originally intended with correct parameter and context?

Comment: Replace `function onComplete()` with `function onComplete(event)` and `tblListener()` with `tblListener(event)`

Comment: Of course.. Thank you very much.  Kind of embarrasing.. lol